# Why isn't the RANK function ranking properly?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that takes a list of values and ranks them from least to greatest. I am using the code below that will not give duplicate ranks.

```
=IF(OR(E51=0,G51=""),"",RANK(G51,$G$1:$G$600,1)+COUNTIF($G$1:$G51,G51)-1)
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2yQp.png]

Throughout the spreadsheet, there are several other duplicate values that give unique ranks, but for some reason this one instance gives a duplicate rank (33).

Any thoughts on what the problem may be? Below is the Evaluate Formula for the two cells which does not give the same RANK value as it should.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I set up your data as pictured, and I can't reproduce the issue. For me, since I don't have all your data, it returns a rank of 3 (with row 52 at rank 1, and row 46 at rank 2). Have you tried using the evaluate formula feature (in the Formulas tab of the ribbon) to see where the calculation may be going wrong?

Comment: =IF(OR(E46=0,G46=""),"",RANK(G46,$G$1:$G$600,1)+COUNTIF($G$1:$G46,G46)-1)

Comment: See above for Evaluate Formula run. No it does not.

Comment: I still don't know why it doesn't work, but I found a fix around. Rounding the value to the 1's place seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

**Fix:** *Using ROUNDUP(1573.77049...,0) to 1574.0 seems to have fixed the issue.*